# Make command wait for confirmation before running next line in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, proxy, command-prompt

I have searched high and low for what I thought would be a common question but can only find answers regarding user confirmation, not system confirmation.

I would like the following commands to run in sequential order, waiting for a response before moving onto the next command:

```
npm config set https-proxy http://example.com:8080
npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
npm config set sslVerify false
npm config set strict-ssl false
set HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:8080
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://example.com:8080
```

I have added the commands to the batch file in sequential order on new lines, but when executing it does not pause on each command to wait for a response. How do I force the script to wait on each command until it’s confirmed by the system?

Comment: The `pause` command is one of the first you typically learn.

Comment: I can have a timed pause and then check the variable to see if it has been set, sure. But what I am asking specifically is a pause that resumes when the standard system confirmation has occurred stating the command has been completed, similar to the event that permits the user to type the next command when using cmd manually

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and especially [MCVE].  What commands are we talking about here?  Post your script, or at least an MCVE.

Comment: I guess I misunderstand what you are trying to ask. Can you [edit] your question to show a few of these problematic commands?

Comment: @DavidDawson You're not using the `start` command to trigger whatever action sets your proxy settings, are you?  If so, that's what's making your commands non-blocking.  If not, and if my answer below doesn't solve your issue, then I agree with tripleee that you should edit your question and post some example code.

Comment: You do know that this is a site to get help with your existing code. Kind if hard to help you troubleshoot it without being able to see it.

Comment: Have modified the post with the commands I am trying to run in sequence within the batch file. They simply set variables/flags and so do not need to be within any functional tree, just need to run in sequential order.

Comment: Isn't NPM a batch-file itself.

Comment: Even if not, it should be `call npm ...`.

Comment: @jwdonahue adding call to the beginning of the npm commands worked. If you write it up I will select as the answer

Comment: @DavidDawson, answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unqualified names like `npm` or `doSomething` may map to scripts written in various languages, including batch files. Use the `call` command to invoke these and cmd.exe will always wait for whatever child process is started.

It's not uncommon for `.exe`'s to be scattered across multiple directories that would bloat the path environment variable, so many installations will lay down alias scripts in a single directory added to the path and when you invoke the command, it figures out what executables to run and launches those.

It's also common to use wrapper scripts to simplify executable invocations, add some logging, or temporarily map the command to a different version (upgrades/testing).

In the case of npm, I believe it's mostly written in JavaScript, so an appropriate scripting engine has to be launched to run the npm commands.  This may be boot-strapped from a batch script or it could be invoked automagically by the OS, based on whatever file extension it has. The details from one version or installation to the next may vary and usually don't matter to the casual user invoking them from the command line, but script behavior can vary noticeably.

Unless you use a fully qualified path/filename to launch something from a command script, and generally even if you do, you should simply default to using the `call` command to invoke it. Then all of the above circumstance are covered and your script will always behave as expected.

```
call npm config set https-proxy http://example.com:8080
call npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
call npm config set sslVerify false
call npm config set strict-ssl false
set HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:8080
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://example.com:8080
```

Note that it is still possible that a script or program could pass work along to another process and then return immediately, but that kind of behavior will normally be the same, whether launched interactively or from a script.